# Change position of System Menu from default position to client area

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, submenu, menubar

I want to **change the position of my system menu** **to the dialog area**. so that my **dialog can be more thin**.

**I am Having my menu Now  Like This**

[image]

**Desired Menu Postion:**

[image]

Please Suggest If Some One have Any idea. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775450(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks for answer but i don't want to make separate menu i just want to place it little bit down.

Comment: You cannot move the system-provided menu bar.

Comment: @HeenaGoyal We are also facing same issue, did you get solution for this?